# Install macOS Big Sur to HFS+ partition on a clean new HDD/SSD

Tags: macos, installation, hfs+, apfs

Is it possible? May be by editing some scripts on the installation media... Or just by selecting a setting I've missed during installation.

And prevent further converting HFS+ to APFS in the future.

I know APFS is newer and better. But I need HFS+.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Both can only be installed on, and boot using, APFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Catalina nor Big Sur will boot from HFS+ [nor install to it]. They will only boot from APFS.
If you need an HFS+ partition, make one separately.

Comment: There is no need for me to have HFS+ partition without macOS installed on it (

Comment: Then tell us what are you actually trying to achieve, rather than how you think you are going to achieve it. This is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I prefer to make the backup image of the operating system volume from an offline one rather than using System Restore or Time Machine. May be it is now became possible to make 1:1 image from an online volume, I just don't want to change my >15 years habits and use different methods. But it looks like I now should, at least with macOS. Actually I know no method how to create an image of the APFS volume. Frankly I don't even understand how this FS works. So I hoped to continue using old good proven ones. I don't care about FS in fact, I just need to be able to image it familiar way. That's it.

Comment: Then that is the question you should have asked. Installing Big Sur to HFS is the Y of your X. You didn't need to know that at all.

Comment: I haven't found any working method of creating/applying an APFS image, that's why I've asked if it is possible to install Big Sur to HFS+ and prevent further conversion.

Comment: You're still looking for the answer to Y.

Comment: Can you please give a straight answer rather than riddles?

Comment: You got the straight answer immediately… "Neither Catalina nor Big Sur will boot from HFS+ [nor install to it]." Everything since has been because that's not the question you actually wanted the answer to.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to say by running in circles but ok.

Answer (score 0):

read this
https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/files/file/985-catalina-mbr-hfs-firmware-check-patch/page/5/?tab=comments#comment-8584

work for me 10.15.

How to finish the Catalina installation.

1. Use EasyMBR-Installer1015 to make USB Catalina Installer.
2. Boot to USB Catalina Installer, open Utilities -> Disk Utility, format as MBR HFS+.

   Install Catalina to blank MBR HFS+ "Target" partition.
3. Boot to USB Catalina Installer, open Utilities -> Terminal, run the script command:
   copytempdata
4. Boot to "Target" MBR HFS+ partition on single user mode (-s), run the script command:
   hfsupdatecache
5. Reboot to "Target" MBR HFS+ partition, setup user name and login, finish the installation.

Also, you need to setup Clover as BooterConfig=0x28, CsrActiveConfig=0x67

Answer (score 0):

That works with Mohave (a method from Insanelymac) pretty well, but starting anything above Mojave in HFS+ is more pain than gain. You will have to perform tricks with bootloader, which are really not worth a time. Catalina and above requires APFS and SSD for correct work.
Yes, you will suffer screen disassembly but SSD will be a great improvement in speed. And you will avoid surges that curse APFS on HDD. Just pick a good SSD like Samsung EVO not to swap it in a couple of years.